# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I am converting my project from vc6 to VS 2010.When I compile my project i get error as below for may .lib inputs. I have added all these lib in the Linker-> Input-> Additional Dependencies, also provided the path of these .lib files in Link->General->Additional Library directories. Any tip on this will be very helpful.

```
lb0.lib(ob0.obj) :error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb1.lib(ob1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb2.lib(ob2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb3.lib(ob3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb3.lib(ob4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb3.lib(ob5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
lb4.lib(0b6.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall SetLastExP(class ExceptionClass *)" (?SetLastExP@@YGXPAVExceptionClass@@@Z)
```

Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think microsoft changed the default TCHAR definition form char to wchar since VC++ 6. It might be that your previous lib is exporting char* in the method signature but your new code is looking for wchar. If this is the case then you could recompile the library, or change the default character set in your new project.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, Both my lib and my project are using only wchar.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to suggest other than check the method signatures very carefully (including call type, parameters). Out of interest, does your program link to any other methods on the zzzClass? Is zzzClass a templated class? Sorry

Comment: are you absolutely sure that zzzClass::SetAaF has a function body in zzz.cpp??

Comment: Yes, the zzzClass::SetAaF has a function body in zzz.cpp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to identify where the `SetLastExP()` function is defined.

- Check that the library that implements SetLastExP is linked.
- Get the .obj file and check with dumpbin if it implements in the decoration that you expect.

  ```
  dumpbin /symbols foo.obj | find "External" | find "SetLastExP"
  ```
- Compare the decoration you see with the decoration you have in the Linker error message.

Probably the function is defined as `extern "C"` while your header file doesn't reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add an other .lib file where SetLastExP() function was defined in cpp file. this redused my error to 13 from 153, now i am left with.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, if you have different Character sets (`Configuration properties` -> `general`) in your subprojects, Visual Studio shows this kind of error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" with an *.obj
```