# error when compiling a project in VS 2010 C ++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I'm trying to compile a project that I created, a software management program, in VS 2010. In VS6 and VS2005, it compiles perfectly.

1 - visual studio 6 2 - Visual Studio 2005 3 - Visual Studio 2010

The original version has some bugs that I would like fix later, but first of all I need it to compile.

With VS 6 and VS 2005 it compiles perfectly.

I added the library **#pragma comment(lib, "bufferoverflowU.lib")** corresponding to each file that needs it (.cpp)

However, it did not solve anything with bufferoverflowU.lib

**errors are:**

```
1>------ Operación Volver a generar todo iniciada: proyecto: Gestion_v1, configuración: Release Win32 ------
1> StdAfx.cpp
1> WDoS.cpp
1> Helpers.cpp
1> Gestion.cpp
1> WWW.cpp
1>WWW.cpp(141): warning C4018: '<' : no coinciden signed/unsigned
1>WWW.cpp(136): warning C4101: 'dwTmp' : variable local sin referencia
1>WWW.cpp(481): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'DWORD' to 'char'; possible loss of data
1>WWW.cpp(482): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'DWORD' to 'char'; possible loss of data
1> Generando código...
1>LINK : warning LNK4108: /ALIGN specified without /DRIVER; image may not run
1>WDoS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie referenced in function "unsigned long __stdcall WDoS_HTTP(void *)" (?WDoS_HTTP@@YGKPAX@Z)
1>Gstion.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
1>WWW.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
1>WDoS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4 referenced in function "unsigned long __stdcall WDoS_HTTP(void *)" (?WDoS_HTTP@@YGKPAX@Z)
1>Gestion.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4 
1>WWW.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
1>.\Release/Gestion_v1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas?
 Thanks

Comment: Can you translate your errors to English? A much wider audience will be able to help diagnose the problem if this was all English.

Comment: OK i've translated to English

Comment: [Have you tried what was done in this thread?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/unresolved-external-symbol-___security_cookie-t1428747.html)

Comment: yes but not work for me, i see this post in another day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your unresolved externals are a consequence of compiling with the [`/GS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx) (Buffer Security Check) compiler flag, but not linking against the CRT (`/NODEFAULTLIB`). If `/GS` is not specified it defaults to being enabled. You can try to disable Buffer Security Checks by specifying `/GS-`.

Alternatively you can attempt to add the pieces of code you need. `__security_cookie` is declared in `<process.h>` and defined in `<gs_cookie.c>` as part of the CRT source that ships with Visual Studio. Since you also explicitly specified `WinMain` as the entry point and don't rely on the CRT to perform the required initialization you will have to call [`__security_init_cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235362.aspx) yourself. There may be more to get this to compile, but this should serve as a starting point.

Comment: Sorry, but <gs_cookie.c> not found and /GS or /GS- command not found, but <process.h> found.

Comment: @aleksander: `<gs_cookie.c>` ships with Visual Studio, unless you are using the Express Edition. It is located under `<VS Install Dir>\VC\crt\src`. `/GS` is a compiler switch, not a command.

Comment: OK, i find the gs_cookie.c file but why dont link in my Visual Studio, i used visual Studio 2010 professional (trial) and not express version, but /GS say not recognize omitted

Comment: thanks, part of the solution works for me i found gs_cookie.c and copy/paste to my directory allways i put this lines of my code #include "gs_cookie.c" and now i get this: `1>WDoS.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4 referenced in function "unsigned long __stdcall WDoS_HTTP(void *)" (?WDoS_HTTP@@YGKPAX@Z)
1>Gestion.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4 
1>WWW.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4`

Comment: @aleksander: As I said, there is more to this. It is a lot easier to just disable Buffer Security Checks altogether. The `/GS` and `/GS-` switches should be supported in your version of Visual Studio 2010. Right-click on your project and select _Properties_. Navigate to _Configuration Properties_ -> _C/C++_ -> _Code Generation_. Under this item change _Buffer Security Check_ from _Yes (/GS)_ to _No (/GS-)_. Alternatively you can specify `/GS-` under _Additional Options_ for the _Command Line_ (also avaliable through the configuration properties).

Answer (score -3):

Make sure your project is not set to unicode. Your library may be that is different.
Try : Project properties -> Configuration properties -> General -> Character set = not set

Ok, try this question :
[error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090609/47733)

Comment: The linker errors are not related to character encoding issues.

Comment: Has proposed the idea that does not work, I tried all the options available and get more utf-8 errors but not errors _security_cookie, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: compiler code: `/OUT:".\Release/Gestion_v1.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "wininet.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:".\Release\Gestion_v1.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /PDB:".\Release/Gestion_v1.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /PGD:"C:\Gestion - copia\Release\Gestion_v1.pgd" /TLBID:1 /ENTRY:"WinMain" /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE  `